# Problems when loading Vaadin/Polymer custom elements (Error message: (0 , $csb__dommodule.DomModule).import is not a function)

Tags: polymer, vaadin, web-component, codesandbox

Could someone please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong here when I try to load a vaadin custom element button, because I get an error message `(0 , $csb__dommodule.DomModule).import is not a function`? TYVM :)

```js
import "@vaadin/vaadin-button";

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
  <h4>Vaadin Button</h4>
  <section>
    <vaadin-button>This is a button</vaadin-button>
  </section>
`;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-swartz-tbe4y?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a codesanbox specific issue. If you run your sandbox locally then it works fine. I just tested that[image]

Steps:

1. export your sandbox
2. run `npm i`
3. run `npm start`

I just created [this issue](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/4747) in codesandbox client repo.

Working webcomponents.dev demo: https://webcomponents.dev/edit/RvnCgQUcXyckBJdjBCgl

**Update:** Linked Codesandbox issue has been fixed :)

Comment: If it is a sandbox issue, try [the WebComponents.dev sandbox](https://webcomponents.dev)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Can we import npm dependencies on webcomponent.dev ? I don't think so. I have raised feature request here https://spectrum.chat/webcomponents-dev/feature-requests/npm-module-import-support~b43eff36-0002-4d63-9ebb-c1b6eaf6ef26

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I just added webcomponents.dev demo. Bare imports automatically works there without having explicit control of package.json

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman OMG what an amazing online IDE this WebComponents.dev is. Things are just working - that's how it should be. Even with JSX I did not have to configure anything. And the best thing is: You change your code, you save it and the changes are visible virtually immediately. However, I would really, really, really love a VIM mode. And I think it has some problems with the "uBlock origin" browser extension (at least on my system). Maybe at least a warning would be nice here, I guess.

Comment: @Natasha yes uBlock origin blocks firebase analytics for that site (error can be seen in console). that's why we have to disable it for this site only.

Comment: I am not on this ``webcomponents.dev`` team (yet). Just a user for now. I do bare Components (no imports nothing, just JS) in JSFiddle still, as it is more stable and faster, in my experience. I even abuse the Svelte REPL for this, as its the fastest REPL I have ever seen.. but Svelte compiles js, so you can't tinker with the output.